# What would motivate choosing between an avalanche or Zener diode?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, noise

If I wanted to produce an analog number generator using reverse-biase diode breakdown, what kind of things should I consider when choosing whether to use an avalanche or Zener diode?

For instance, perhaps I'd want to choose a Zener diode since the junction isn't destroyed during breakdown? But perhaps I my electric field intensity is limited, which makes it easier to use an avalanche device. And does the junction being destroyed matter? Does it mean I can only breakdown the diode once? Suppose I have all the materials typically provided for a laboratory at a university.